# Mostrar solamente Personas que tengan un valor en concreto (Firebase)

Tags: java, android, firebase

Tengo un `recyclerview` que cargo desde una *database* que tengo en *Firebase*, lo hago así:

```
    databaseReference.child("Personas").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            listPersonas.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Personas.class));
            displayPersonas(listPersonas);
        }
```

En *Firebase* sería algo así,

Personas/id/

- datospersona: valor
- mostrar: valor

Pues lo que me gustaría conseguir es que cuando el valor de *mostrar* sea por ejemplo *true* ese item no se muestre en `recyclerview` los demás que no tengan ese valor en *mostrar* sí.

¿Cómo podría realizar esto? Gracias!

Comment: Si no malinterpreto tu consulta, no podrías simplemente realizar listPersonas.add condicionalmente dependiendo del valor de "mostrar"? O si te interesa mantener a la persona igual en la lista, filtrar la colección al momento de mostrar en la view?

Comment: Mmmm, lo que necesito es que si contiene ese valor no se muestre ese *item* en `RecyclerView` si crees que con lo que comentas se puede realizar, por favor, crea una respuesta :) @mmartinez7 , sería algo así como "ocultar" esa persona si el valor es "true"

Comment: Y cual sería el impedimento de recorrer listPersonas y crear una nueva lista a partir de ella con todas las Personas cuyo "mostrar" sea "true" y luego pasarle ese listado a displayPersonas?

Comment: Se podría intentar, creo que funcionaría para lo que necesito! Podrías explicar como realizarlo? Gracias! @mmartinez7

Comment: Lo agregue como respuesta, hazme saber si era realmente lo que necesitabas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resumiendo los comentarios:

A la lista `Persona`s que maneja el recyclerview puedes filtrarla segun el atributo `mostrar`, creando una nueva lista la cual le pasarias a tu metodo `displayPersonas`

De esa manera tu `listaPersonas` se mantiene siempre igual y en la view presentas un listado filtrado.

Eso lo puedes lograr simplemente iterando y agregando los elementos cuyo `mostrar == true`

```
databaseReference.child("Personas").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            listPersonas.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Personas.class));
            displayPersonas(filtrarPersonas(listPersonas));
        }


private List<Persona> filtrarPersonas(List<Persona> original){
    List<Persona> personasAMostrar = new ArrayList<Persona>():
    if(original!=null){
        for(Persona p : original){
            if(p.getMostrar()){
                personasAMostrar.add(p); // o add(p.clone()), podria interesarte tener la misma referencia o no, eso depende de la logica de negocio de tu app
            }
        }
    }
    return personasAMostrar;
}
```

EDIT: Si no te interesa mantener `listaPersonas` con las personas con `mostrar = false` puedes evitar filtrar la lista y simplemente no agregar esos elementos:

```
databaseReference.child("Personas").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Persona p = dataSnapshot.getValue(Personas.class);
            if(p.getMostrar()){
               listPersonas.add(p);
              }        
            displayPersonas(listPersonas);
        }
```

Comment: Funciona correctamente para lo que necesito, gracias @mmartinez7 :)!