# Mostrar item según el valor en Sqlite

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Hace poco hice una [pregunta parecida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/77108/mostrar-solamente-personas-que-tengan-un-valor-en-concreto-firebase) a esta, pero no la misma, he intentando implementar esa lógica ahora, pero no sé como podría hacerlo, así que realizo la pregunta.

Necesito que se muestren solamente los *item* en los cuales el valor de `getTitulo()` sea **diario**, los que tengan otro valor o ninguno no se muestren en `RecyclerView`.

`Activity`

```
public static SqliteDatabase mDatabase;
public static RecyclerView recordatoriosView;
public static ArrayList<Notas> allRecordatorios;
public static TextView TxtPersistente, RecyclerVacio;
static public NotasAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RecyclerVacio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerVacio);
    FrameLayout fLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_to_do);

    recordatoriosView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recordatorios_list);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    TxtPersistente = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    recordatoriosView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recordatoriosView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mDatabase = new SqliteDatabase(this);
    allRecordatorios = (ArrayList<Notas>) mDatabase.listNotas();

    if (allRecordatorios.size() > 0) {
        RecyclerVacio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        recordatoriosView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAdapter = new NotasAdapter(this, allRecordatorios);
        recordatoriosView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    } else {
        recordatoriosView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        RecyclerVacio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

`SqliteDatabase`

```
public class SqliteDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DB_NOTAS";
    private static final String TABLE_NOTAS = "NOTAS";

    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_TITULO = "titulo";
    private static final String COLUMN_NOTAS = "notas";
    private static final String COLUMN_FECHA = "fecha";
    private static final String COLUMN_PERSISTENTE = "persistente";


    public SqliteDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String  CREATE_NOTAS_TABLE = "CREATE    TABLE " + TABLE_NOTAS + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_TITULO + " TEXT," + COLUMN_NOTAS + " TEXT," + COLUMN_FECHA + " TEXT," + COLUMN_PERSISTENTE + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_NOTAS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NOTAS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public List<Notas> listNotas(){
        String sql = "select * from " + TABLE_NOTAS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<Notas> storeNotas = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                int id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
                String titulo = cursor.getString(1);
                String notas = cursor.getString(2);
                String fecha = cursor.getString(3);
                String persistente = cursor.getString(4);
                storeNotas.add(new Notas(id, titulo, notas, fecha, persistente));
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return storeNotas;
    }

    public void addNotas(Notas notas){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_TITULO, notas.getTitulo());
        values.put(COLUMN_NOTAS, notas.getNotas());
        values.put(COLUMN_FECHA, notas.getFecha());
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSISTENTE, notas.getPersistente());
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_NOTAS, null, values);
    }

    public void updateNotas(Notas notas){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_TITULO, notas.getTitulo());
        values.put(COLUMN_NOTAS, notas.getNotas());
        values.put(COLUMN_FECHA, notas.getFecha());
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSISTENTE, notas.getPersistente());
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.update(TABLE_NOTAS, values, COLUMN_ID    + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(notas.getId())});
    }

    public void deleteNotas(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NOTAS, COLUMN_ID    + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id)});
    }
}
```

`NotasAdapter`

```
public class NotasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotasAdapter.NotasViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    public static ArrayList<Notas> listNotas;
    private SqliteDatabase mDatabase;

    public NotasAdapter(Context context, List<Notas> listNotas) {
        this.context = context;
        Collections.reverse(listNotas);
        this.listNotas = (ArrayList<Notas>) listNotas;
        mDatabase = new SqliteDatabase(context);
    }

    @Override
    public NotasViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.notas_list_adapter, parent, false);
        return new NotasViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NotasViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Notas singleNotas = listNotas.get(position);
        if((position % 2) == 0)
            holder.cardview_item.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f7f7f7"));
        else
            holder.cardview_item.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ededed"));
        holder.txt_titulo.setText(singleNotas.getTitulo());
        holder.txt_nota.setText(singleNotas.getNotas());
        holder.txt_fecha.setText(singleNotas.getFecha());
        holder.txt_persistente.setText(singleNotas.getPersistente());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listNotas.size();
    }

    public class NotasViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView txt_titulo, txt_nota, txt_fecha, txt_persistente;
        public ImageView edit_nota, delete_nota;
        public CardView cardview_item;

        public NotasViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txt_titulo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_titulo);
            txt_nota = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_nota);
            txt_fecha = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_fecha);
            txt_persistente = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_persistente);
            edit_nota = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit_nota);
            delete_nota = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_nota);
            cardview_item = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: La solución seguro que está o en el query a la base de datos o en el adapter. Mucho más con el código de la pregunta no te puedo decir. No veo ni que item sea una variable ni tampoco la variable "datos" a la que haces referencia.

Comment: Hola @Juan ! He añadido lo que me comentas, gracias !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta solución permite el filtrado de los datos en el `Adapter` pudiendo cambiar de criterio desde el `Activity` llamando al metodo filter(criterio) del `Adapter` con el criterio deseado. Por ejemplo asociando un criterio distinto (diario, mensual, etc) a distintos botones de la actividad.

Al `Adapter` le hacemos guardar una copia de los datos originales y mostramos una vista filtrada de los mismos cada vez que se llama al metodo `filter()` con el nuevo criterio.

La pregunta ya está contestada, pero ya tenía el 80% escrito así que igualmente dejo la respuesta en caso de que a alguno le venga bien.

```
public class NotasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotasAdapter.NotasViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    public static ArrayList<Notas> listNotas;
    public ArrayList<Notas> copiaDeLista;
    private SqliteDatabase mDatabase;

    public NotasAdapter(Context context, List<Notas> listNotas) {
        this.context = context;
        Collections.reverse(listNotas);
        this.listNotas = (ArrayList<Notas>) listNotas;
        this.copiaDeLista = new ArrayList<>();
        this.copiaDeLista.addAll(this.listNotas);
        mDatabase = new SqliteDatabase(context);
    }

    public void filter(String  criterio) {
        this.listNotas.clear();
        if(criterio == null || criterio.equals("")){ // Mostrar Todo
            this.listNotas.addAll(this.copiaDeLista);
        } else{
            if(criterio.equals("diario")){ //Mostrar diario
                for(Notas nota : this.copiaDeLista) {
                    if(nota.getTitulo().equals("diario")){ //Esta es la condicion que dice si aparece o no
                        this.listNotas.add(nota);
                    }
                }    
            }

             //.... Aca el filtrado por el resto de los criterios

        }
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public NotasViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.notas_list_adapter, parent, false);
        return new NotasViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NotasViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Notas singleNotas = listNotas.get(position);
        if((position % 2) == 0)
            holder.cardview_item.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f7f7f7"));
        else
            holder.cardview_item.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ededed"));
        holder.txt_titulo.setText(singleNotas.getTitulo());
        holder.txt_nota.setText(singleNotas.getNotas());
        holder.txt_fecha.setText(singleNotas.getFecha());
        holder.txt_persistente.setText(singleNotas.getPersistente());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listNotas.size();
    }



    public class NotasViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView txt_titulo, txt_nota, txt_fecha, txt_persistente;
        public ImageView edit_nota, delete_nota;
        public CardView cardview_item;

        public NotasViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txt_titulo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_titulo);
            txt_nota = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_nota);
            txt_fecha = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_fecha);
            txt_persistente = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_persistente);
            edit_nota = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit_nota);
            delete_nota = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_nota);
            cardview_item = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_item);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDICIÓN 1**

Un ejemplo de como usarlo desde el activity con 4 botones.

```
public static SqliteDatabase mDatabase;
public static RecyclerView recordatoriosView;
public static ArrayList<Notas> allRecordatorios;
public static TextView TxtPersistente, RecyclerVacio;
static public NotasAdapter mAdapter; 

//Supongamos que esto son botones que están en el layout
private Button filtrarTodos, filtrarDiario, filtrarMensual, filtrarSemanal;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RecyclerVacio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerVacio);
    FrameLayout fLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_to_do);

    filtrarTodos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFiltrarTodos);
    filtrarTodos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(){
            mAdapter.filter("");
        }
    });

    filtrarDiario = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFiltrarDiario);
    filtrarDiario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(){
            mAdapter.filter("diario");
        }
    });

    filtrarSemanal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFiltrarSemanal);
    filtrarSemanal..setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(){
            mAdapter.filter("semanal");
        }
    });

    filtrarMensual = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFiltrarMensual);
    filtrarMensual..setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(){
            mAdapter.filter("mensual");
        }
    });

    recordatoriosView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recordatorios_list);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    TxtPersistente = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    recordatoriosView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recordatoriosView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mDatabase = new SqliteDatabase(this);
    allRecordatorios = (ArrayList<Notas>) mDatabase.listNotas();

    if (allRecordatorios.size() > 0) {
        RecyclerVacio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        recordatoriosView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAdapter = new NotasAdapter(this, allRecordatorios);
        recordatoriosView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    } else {
        recordatoriosView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        RecyclerVacio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: Puede que esta respuesta se ajuste aún más a mis necesidades, pero podrías poner un ejemplo de como llamarlo desde la `Activity`? Ya que lo he intentando pero se me cierra, gracias @Juan !

Comment: Ahí te agregué una forma de usarlo en la actividad. Si la respuesta te sirve por lo menos dale un +1 ;)

Comment: Gracias! Por supuesto, luego probaré y si se ajusta más a lo que necesito daré esta como valida! Por cierto, si tienes tiempo pasate por esta otra pregunta que hice: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/81013/añadir-texto-favorito-y-si-ya-está-borrarlo-sqlite

Comment: Marco como solución, finalmente he cedido usar este método ya que se ajustaba más a mis necesidades, pero ambos son validos, gracias !!

Comment: Revisa el uso de memoria con ambos métodos. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Si necesitas un query en que solamente se devuelven las filas con un titulo particular, puedes usar:

```
public List<Notas> listNotasPorTitulo(String titulo){
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NOTAS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_TITULO + " = ?";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    List<Notas> storeNotas = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{titulo});
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            int id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
            String titulo = cursor.getString(1);
            String notas = cursor.getString(2);
            String fecha = cursor.getString(3);
            String persistente = cursor.getString(4);
            storeNotas.add(new Notas(id, titulo, notas, fecha, persistente));
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return storeNotas;
}
```

Ahora puedes en tus actividades eligir como filtrar tu resultado. Ejemplo:

- Activity1 : `listNotasPorTitulo("diario")`
- Activity2 : `listNotasPorTitulo("semanal")`
- etc...

Comment: Hace exactamente lo que buscaba, pero no hay forma de realizarlo desde la `Activity`? por ejemplo, imaginemos que tengo tres `Activity`, sería `Activity1` devolver las filas donde titulo sea "diario", `Activity2`, donde sea "semanal", `Activity3` donde sea "mensual", tendría que crear tres `list` distintas. @StefanNolde sino es posible lo que comento, pues marco ya como solución, gracias !  :)

Comment: Te lo edito con una solucion más generico. usa un parámetro en el método y llamalo desde tus actividades con lo que quieres filtrar.

Comment: Gracias @StefanNolde !! Justo lo que necesitaba :)