# Añadir texto "Favorito" y si ya está, borrarlo (Sqlite)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Intento que al hacer clic en un item de mi `RecyclerView` escribir la palabra *favorito* en la columna **FAVORITOS**.

Hago lo siguiente, obtengo la *id* y luego añado la palabra *favorito*

Método en `Sqlite`: Aquí creo que es donde está el error, que no envía "favorito" a la tabla.

```
public void FavNotas(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NOTAS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_FAVORITO + " = ?";
    db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{"favorito"}); String.valueOf(id);
}
```

Y luego desde el `Adapter`

```
holder.cardview_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mDatabase.FavNotas(singleNotas.getId());
            }
        });
```

La idea es que al hacer clic se envíe *favorito* pero si hago clic y ya tiene la palabra *favorito* la borre.

No recibo ningún error, simplemente no hace esa función y el problema está en el método de `Sqlite` pero no sé como hacer el método correctamente para lo que quiero

**EDITO1:**

`Sqlite`

```
public class SqliteDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DB_NOTAS";
    private static final String TABLE_NOTAS = "NOTAS";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_TITULO = "titulo";
    private static final String COLUMN_NOTAS = "notas";
    private static final String COLUMN_FECHA = "fecha";
    private static final String COLUMN_FAVORITO = "favorito";
    private static final String COLUMN_CATEGORIA = "categoria";


    public SqliteDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String  CREATE_NOTAS_TABLE = "CREATE    TABLE " + TABLE_NOTAS + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_TITULO + " TEXT," + COLUMN_NOTAS + " TEXT," + COLUMN_FECHA + " TEXT," + COLUMN_FAVORITO + " TEXT," + COLUMN_CATEGORIA + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_NOTAS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NOTAS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public List<Notas> listNotasPorTitulo(String titulos){
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NOTAS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_CATEGORIA + " = ?";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<Notas> storeNotas = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{titulos});
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                int id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
                String titulo = cursor.getString(1);
                String notas = cursor.getString(2);
                String fecha = cursor.getString(3);
                String favorito = cursor.getString(4);
                String categoria = cursor.getString(5);
                storeNotas.add(new Notas(id, titulo, notas, fecha, favorito, categoria));
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return storeNotas;
    }

    public List<Notas> listNotas(){
        String sql = "select * from " + TABLE_NOTAS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<Notas> storeNotas = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                int id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
                String titulo = cursor.getString(1);
                String notas = cursor.getString(2);
                String fecha = cursor.getString(3);
                String favorito = cursor.getString(4);
                String categoria = cursor.getString(5);
                storeNotas.add(new Notas(id, titulo, notas, fecha, favorito, categoria));
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return storeNotas;
    }

    public void addNotas(Notas notas){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_TITULO, notas.getTitulo());
        values.put(COLUMN_NOTAS, notas.getNotas());
        values.put(COLUMN_FECHA, notas.getFecha());
        values.put(COLUMN_FAVORITO, notas.getPersistente());
        values.put(COLUMN_CATEGORIA, notas.getCategoria());
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_NOTAS, null, values);
    }

    public void updateNotas(Notas notas){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_TITULO, notas.getTitulo());
        values.put(COLUMN_NOTAS, notas.getNotas());
        values.put(COLUMN_FECHA, notas.getFecha());
        values.put(COLUMN_FAVORITO, notas.getPersistente());
        values.put(COLUMN_CATEGORIA, notas.getCategoria());
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.update(TABLE_NOTAS, values, COLUMN_ID    + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(notas.getId())});
    }

    public List<Notas> findNotas() {
        List<Notas> lista_notas = new ArrayList<Notas>();
        String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_NOTAS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_NOTAS + " = " + "notas";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Notas mNotas = null;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            do {
                int id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
                String titulo = cursor.getString(1);
                String notas = cursor.getString(2);
                String fecha = cursor.getString(3);
                String favorito = cursor.getString(4);
                String categoria = cursor.getString(5);
                mNotas = new Notas(id, titulo, notas, fecha, favorito, categoria);
                lista_notas.add(mNotas);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            db.close();
            cursor.close();
            return lista_notas;
        } else {
            db.close();
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }

    }

    public void deleteNotas(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NOTAS, COLUMN_ID    + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id)});
    }

    public void FavNotas(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NOTAS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_FAVORITO + " = ?";
        db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{"favorito"}); String.valueOf(id);
    }
}
```

`Adapter`

```
   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NotasViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Notas singleNotas = listNotas.get(position);

        holder.delete_nota.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //delete row from database
                mDatabase.deleteNotas(singleNotas.getId());
                ActualizaRecyclerView();
            }
        });

        // método para añadir fav
        holder.cardview_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mDatabase.FavNotas(singleNotas.getId());
                ActualizaRecyclerView();
            }
        });
    }
```

`Notas`

```
  public String getFavorito() {
        return favorito;
    }

    public void setFavorito(String favorito) {
        this.favorito = favorito;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo, el método FavNotas lo único que hace es ejecutar una query que regresa todas las notas que estén marcadas como "favorito". Si quisiera marcar o desmarcar como favorita una nota dado un id haría lo siguiente

```
public void FavNotas(int id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "SELECT " + COLUMN_FAVORITO + " FROM " + TABLE_NOTAS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + " = ?";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    String val = "";

    if (!cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_FAVORITO)).equals("favorito"))
    {
        val = "favorito"
    }

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_FAVORITO, val);
    db.update(TABLE_NOTAS, values, COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id)});
}
```

Comment: Es exactamente lo que buscaba! Por cierto, una última duda, cómo puedo hacer para que si es "favorito" este botón (que tengo en `onBindViewHolder`, en static) `delete_nota.setVisibility(VISIBLE);` se muestre en el item, pero si está vacío se esconda?

Comment: No estoy seguro de como esté implementado, pero lo que haría sería checar si es o no favorito y así como tu lo pones utilizar el método `setVisibility`

Comment: Es lo que estaba pensando! Gracias por tu respuesta, me lo soluciono a la perfección, marco como solucionado! :)

Answer (score 1):

La forma en que lo haría es tener en la clase Notas el atributo esFavorito.
Ese atributo se setea cuando lees la lista de notas desde la base de datos.

Luego

```
holder.cardview_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Notas nota = listaNotas.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                nota.setFavorito(!nota.getFavorito()); //Si esta prendido lo apagamos o viceversa
                <ACA ACTUALIZAR LA NOTA EN LA BD CON SU NUEVO ESTADO DE FAVORITO>
                <ACA LLAMAR METODO QUE ACTUALIZA LA INTERFAZ DE USUARIO>
            }
        });
```

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta con más información, a ver si así me puedes ayudar mejor, gracias ! Lo que necesito es que al hacer clic en `cardview_item` se añada en la columna de favoritos, "favorito" y si al volver a hacer clic está el texto, lo borre, pero no consigo realizarlo

Comment: Cuando decís columna me imagino que es la columna de la base de datos. El query supongo que lo tenés o lo podés hacer. En la respuesta te digo como manejar el click. Si es o no favorito deberia ser un atributo de la nota. Al recibir el click actualizas el estado de dicho atributo en el objeto nota asociado al holder, que es una nota de tu arraylist. Y luego grabas el dato actualizado en la base de datos.